# Ist „je“ in „je noch so kleinste“ richtig verwendet?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

Ich kann mittels einer Internetsuche nicht direkt bestätigen, ob der folgende Satz richtig ist:

> Das *je* noch so kleinste Detail ist … worden.

Ich weiß nicht ob *je* wirklich da sein darf. Und wenn, was für einen Effekt das hat. Oder, wenn ich es falsch gehört habe, gibt es ein Wort, welches als Ersatz für *je* fungieren könnte? (Wobei ich fast sicher bin, ich habe „noch so kleinste“ gewissermaßen richtig mitbekommen).

---

(Übersetzungsversuch: „Even the littlest of the details was ...“)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nein, das ist nicht deutsch.
Eine korrekte Übersetzung wäre:

> Selbst das kleinste Detail war...

Or, if you need more stress on how small the detail is:

> Selbst das allerkleinste Detail war...

If you wanted the detail not small in form(only), but in value, you could substitute *klein* with *gering*, so you would use

> das (aller)geringste

Comment: Danke. Ich entschuldige mich für die Verwirrung. Ich wollte eigentlich nach einer festen oder mindestens möglichen Konstruktion, wobei  "noch so kleinste" immernoch erscheint. Es ist eher der deutsche Ausdruck und nicht dessen Übersetzung was mich interessierte.

Comment: @c.p. Eine Formulierung wie "Selbst ein noch so kleines Detail" wäre machbar. Im Superlativ klingt es in meinen Ohren nicht korrekt.

Comment: **Jedes noch so kleinste Detail...** fehlt in der Liste.

Comment: @Takkat... sollte das nicht "noch so kleine" sein? Für mich klingt der Superlativ tiemlich falsch.

Comment: @Emanuel: geht beides, mit dem Superlativ wird es dann noch einmal zugespitzt.

Comment: @Takkat: Superlativ kling für mich "überspitzt", da hören meine Ohren dasselbe wie Emanuel.

Comment: @Stephie "überspitzt" ist ja nicht falsch, und in der Frage steht der Superlativ.

Comment: @Stephie... ich hab' jetzt mal bei Google books geguckt und es wird anscheinend geschrieben.  https://www.google.de/search?q=%22noch+so+kleinste%22&btnG=Nach+B%C3%BCchern+suchen&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=de  ... ist vielleicht schlechter Stil, vielleicht auch einfach nur selten, aber falsch dann wohl doch nicht.

Comment: @Takkat Es ist eine Kontamination der Wendungen *selbst das kleinste*, *jedes noch so kleine* und *jedes kleinste*. Jedes hat seine Logik, als Mischung klingen sie einfach alle nur irgendwie vertraut, ohne "the real thing" zu sein.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: gut möglich, Sprache macht so etwas - man kann auch nicht feststellen, ob etwas *richtig* oder *falsch* ist, sondern nur beobachten, ob die Leute es benutzen oder nicht. ([128000](https://www.google.de/search?q="jedes+noch+so+kleinste") gegenüber [320000](https://www.google.de/search?q="jedes+noch+so+kleine") Google hits) :)

Comment: @Takkat Kann man schon, wenn es auch noch logisch falsch ist, siehe meine Antwort in Emanuels Folgefrage (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22541/noch-so-adjektivste-korrekt-stilistisch-wackelig-oder-falsch). Die Mehrheit ist an sprachlichen Fragen leider nicht interessiert, deshalb sollte man sich auch nicht unbedingt daran halten.

Answer (score 1):

Du wirst "ja noch so" gehört haben, was als reiner Verstärker funktioniert und in deinem Beispiel auch noch idiomatisch falsch verwendet wurde, da es eigentlich als implizite Entschuldigung verwendet wird (Bsp.: "Ich bin ja noch so klein.").

Richtig wäre die Verwendung von "noch so" gewesen, was bei "noch so klein" das Gleiche wie "beliebig klein" bedeutet.