# "Jedes/r/e/n... noch so" mit Adjektiv im Superlativ - korrekt, stilistisch wackelig oder falsch

Tags: style

In einer anderen [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22538/1224) wurde unlängst die Formulierung

> Jeder noch so kleinste ...

verwendet. Das kam mir (und auch einigen anderen) komisch vor, allerdings ergab eine schnelle Suche bei Google Books, dass die Formulierung durchaus verwendet wird.
Trotzdem konnte ich mich nicht damit anfreunden und habe daher über andere Beispiele nachgedacht. Hier eine Auswahl:

> Jedes noch so teuerste Geschenk kann mich nicht trösten.
>   Kein noch so leckerster Wein kann einem Bier das Wasser reichen.
>   Jeder noch so unscheinbarste Fehler ist zu vermeiden.

Die klingen für mich alle grob falsch. Ich glaube, es liegt daran, dass die Formulierung an sich einen Plural referenziert, was mit einem Superlativ im Singular kollidiert.

- Ist diese Formulierung grammatisch richtig?
- Ist sie stilistisch akzeptabel?
- Wenn nein: warum ist es bei "kleinste" nicht ganz so übel?
- Gibt es weitere Adjektive, für die es funktioniert?

Comment: Im ersten Beispiel fehlt das "so". Die Antwort auf deine Frage: Die Verwendung des Superlativs ist falsch. Es muss lauten: "Jedes noch so teure Geschenk", "Kein noch so leckerer Wein...", "Jeder noch so unscheibare Fehler...".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es gibt zwar keinen offensichtlichen grammatischen oder syntaktischen Fehler, trotzdem ist die Formulierung nicht korrekt. Es handelt sich um eine typische "Kontamination", eine Vermischung zweier Wendungen. Es heißt nämlich entweder

> jeder kleinste Fehler...

oder

> jeder noch so kleine Fehler...

Letztere Wendung leitet sich ab von

> jeder Fehler, und wäre er auch noch so klein, ...

Die *ursprüngliche Gestalt dieser Wendung* "und noch so..." (siehe [Grimm-WB "noch" adv. II,2](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN05834)) war:

> und wäre er auch ***noch einmal*** so klein...

d.h. doppelt so klein bzw. halb so groß. Davon ist nur das *noch* übriggeblieben. Hier ist leicht zu erkennen, dass die Formulierung

*...und wäre er auch noch (einmal) so kleinst...* bzw. *jeder noch (einmal) so kleinste...*

ein logischer Fehler wäre.

Die beiden speziellen Wendungen werden auch mit "winzig", "gering", "minimal" etc. gebraucht. Im Prinzip ist die Konstruktion mit jedem Adjektiv möglich, wenn es darum geht auszudrücken, dass es keine Toleranzen gibt oder alle Möglichkeiten ausgeschöpft wurden:

> *Auch das teuerste* Geschenk konnte sie nicht trösten. (© Emanuel;-)
>
> *Selbst an der geradesten* Linie hatte er noch etwas auszusetzen.

oder

> *Kein noch so verzweifelter* Appell brachte ihn davon ab, in sein Verderben zu rennen.
>
> *Jeder noch so verzweifelte* Appell prallte an ihm ab.

Comment: Da beide Antworten keine Belege liefern, ist dies wohl eine Abstimmung über die Korrektheit. Ich stimme mit Dir ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Tut mir leid, für mich war das so evident, dass ich den Beleg schuldig geblieben bin. Ich habe das jetzt nachgetragen.

Comment: As I said, I agree :)

Answer (score 3):

Also ich würde sagen, dass beispielsweise der Satz

> Jeder noch so kleinste Fehler sollte vermieden werden.

korrekt ist. Es handelt sich dabei jedoch um eine Ausnahme und nicht um eine Regel, dass man den Superlativ in diesem Zusammenhang verwendet. Vielleicht erscheint er mir auch nur als korrekt, da man es umgangssprachlich verwenden würde. Der Satz

> Jeder noch so kleine Fehler sollte vermieden werden.

hört sich für mich besser an.

Die anderen von dir angesprochenen Sätze sind in diesem Zusammenhang nicht korrekt und müssten wie folgt lauten:

> Jedes noch so teure Geschenk kann mich nicht trösten.
>
> Kein noch so leckerer Wein kann einem Bier das Wasser reichen.
>
> Jeder noch so unscheinbare Fehler ist zu vermeiden.

Comment: Nein, der Superlativ ist hier mE falsch, es müsste "jeder noch so **kleine** Fehler" heißen. Warum sollte gerade _klein_ eine Ausnahme darstellen?

Comment: Weil ich mir vorstellen kann, das ich es so umgangssprachlich verwenden würde, wenn ich "klein" besonders betonen will. Es kann natürlich sein, das es nicht korrekt ist, habe ich ja auch erwähnt.

Comment: Du sagtest _Also ich würde sagen, dass beispielsweise der Satz ... korrekt ist_. Ich bin, jedenfalls in Bezug auf die Schriftsprache, nicht dieser Meinung; übrigens würde ich selbst diese Konstruktion auch mündlich nicht verwenden.

Comment: @Ingmar... naja, aber es gibt einige Bücher wo's drinsteht. Auch ein sicherlich lektoriertes Wallraff-Buch ist darunter   https://www.google.de/search?q=%22noch+so+kleinste%22&hl=de&tbm=bks&ei=3TcUVYbkGoLuate9gNgE&start=60&sa=N

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe die Formulierung »jeder noch so kleinste« zwar noch nicht bewusst wahrgenommen, aber im Internet scheint sie weit verbreitet zu sein. Sucht man bei Google nach »"jeder noch so kleine"« (mit Eingabe der hier dargestellten Anführungszeichen um genau diese Phrase zu suchen) und nach »"jeder noch so kleinste"«, findet man diese Trefferzahlen:

> "jeder noch so kleine": Ungefähr 67.600 Ergebnisse
>   "jeder noch so kleinste": Ungefähr 45.100 Ergebnisse

Bing findet nicht nur weniger Treffer, sondern auch ein dramatisch anderes Verhältnis:

> "jeder noch so kleine": 32.400 Ergebnisse
>   "jeder noch so kleinste": 1.230 Ergebnisse

Alle übrigen Suchmaschinen basieren auf einer dieser beiden Maschinen, liefern daher auch ähnliche Zahlen, oder zeigen leider keine Trefferzahlen an.

Ich halte das Ergebnis von Bing für plausibler, aber selbst hier kommt auf 26-mal »...kleine« einmal »kleinste«. Das ist mehr als man erwarten kann, wenn die Superlativ-Variante rein nur darauf zurückzuführen wollte, dass Menschen, die schlecht Deutsch sprechen, einen Fehler machen.

Daher orte ich hier eine sich anbahnende Änderung des Sprachgebrauchs. Wie jede derartige Änderung ruft sie am Beginn alle Sprachpolizisten der deutschsprachigen Länder auf den Plan, die alle laut »Fehler!« rufen, und den Untergang der deutschsprachigen Kultur beweinen.

Tatsache ist aber, dass Sprache lebt und sich im Lauf der Zeit ändert.

Zu den Regeln einer Sprache gibt es zwei Ansichten, die einander zwar auf gewisse Weise widersprechen, aber trotzdem beide im jeweiligen Kontext richtig sind:

### Sprach-Regeln sind deskriptiv

Der tatsächliche Gebrauch einer Sprache durch ihre Sprecher wird nicht von expliziten Regeln vorgegeben. Kleinkinder, die eine Sprache lernen, lernen keine Regeln, und zwei Menschen, die sich im Kaffeehaus über ein beliebiges Thema unterhalten, denken beim Bilden ihrer Sätze so gut wie nie an die jeweiligen Regeln.

Es ist nämlich umgekehrt: Menschen benutzen Sprache. Dazu folgen sie zwar Regeln, aber das sind implizite Regeln, die einen in der Regel nicht bewusst sind. Germanisten, oder Linguisten sind bestrebt, aus den Äußerungen ihrer Mitmenschen genau diese Regeln herauszudestillieren. Dadurch entsteht ein Satz von Regeln, der **beschreibt** wie sich Menschen unterhalten.

### Sprach-Regeln sind normativ

Der gegenteilige Denkansatz sieht die Regeln als eine Menge von Vorschriften, an die man sich zu halten hat, wenn man eine Sprache korrekt benutzen will. Dieser Ansatz ist der, dem der Sprachunterricht an Schulen und anderen Bildungsstätten zugrunde liegt, und den Erwerb einer Fremd-Sprache nicht nur erleichtert, sondern vermutlich sogar erst ermöglicht.

Der Unterschied zwischen beiden Ansichten wird dann offenbar, wenn tatsächlicher Sprachgebrauch und Regelsatz nicht mehr 1:1 zueinander passen. Der normative Ansatz sieht jede Abweichung von den Regeln sofort als Fehler. Der deskriptive Ansatz kennt keine falsche Sprach-Verwendung, sondern höchstens ungenügend formulierte Regeln.

Ich glaube, dass wir mit »jeder noch so `superlativ`« gerade erleben, wie Gebrauch und Regeln auseinander driften. Die Vertreter der Ansicht, Regeln wären normativ, sind die, die darin Fehler sehen, die zu korrigieren sind. Das deskriptive Lager zuckt mit den Schultern und erweitert gelassen eine der vielen Regeln.

Bis jedoch aus den lässig geänderten deskriptiven Regeln neue normative Regeln werden, die auch im offiziellen Sprachunterricht Einzug halten, vergehen oftmals mehrere Jahrzehnte.

Comment: Was ist DEINE konkrete Antwort auf die Frage? Welche Variante hältst du selbst für die aus sprachlicher Sicht für die besser vertretbare, anstatt die Entscheidung an amorphe und in ihrem Zustandekommen völlig undurchsichtige Suchmaschinen-Trefferzahlen zu delegieren? Dir ist – als IT-Spezialisten und Internetkenner – auch sicherlich klar, dass Internetquellen noch exponentiell mehr ungeprüft voneinander abschreiben (inklusive aller Schreibvarianten) als dies schon im gedruckten Bereich der Fall ist. (->)

Comment: Ich habe den Eindruck, die ständige Berufung auf die Häufigkeit eines bestimmten Sprachgebrauchs im Internet macht Sites wie diese im Prinzip obsolet, weil man nach dieser Logik ja hier keine Frage mehr stellen muss, sondern mit Google etc. sucht, welche Variante dort häufiger ist. Die Frage nach dem Wie, Warum usw. muss dann ja nicht mehr gestellt werden. Wozu versammeln wir uns hier eigentlich? Zu deinen Ausführungen zum sich ändernden Sprachgebrauch hätte der eine oder andere Beleg nicht geschadet. (->)

Comment: Die Sprache ist ein äußerst komplexes und vielseitiges Gebilde, und "den Sprachgebrauch" gibt es nicht. Veränderungen passieren in allen ihren Bereichen, aber in sehr unterschiedlichem Ausmaß und mit unterschiedlicher Geschwindigkeit, und wir alle tragen mit unserer Sprachpraxis dazu bei oder eben nicht. Regeln dienen der Aufrechterhaltung der Konvention und sind keine "polizeilichen Maßnahmen". Wie beliebig du hier die deskriptive und die normative Linguistik gegeneinander ausspielst, finde ich abenteuerlich.

Comment: Eine lebendige Sprache hält sich nicht an festgesetzte Regeln, sondern Regeln werden nach dem Sprachgebrauch festgesetzt. Man findet die Kombination mit dem Superlativ übrigens auch schon vereinzelt im 19. Jahrhundert; sie ist also nicht so neu, wie man meinen könnte.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: Ich hätte gedacht, meinen Standpunkt klar dargelegt zu haben. Kurzfassung: Die Regeln bilden den Gebrauch der Sprache ab, sind also deskriptiv. In der Lehre haben dieselben Regeln aber einen normativen Charakter. Lebende Sprachen verändern sich, und ich glaube, dass wir hier eine gerade stattfindende Veränderung beobachten können, die vor allem dort auf Widerstand stößt, wo man den normativen Charakter der Sprach-Regeln über das eigentlich grundlegende deskriptive Wesen der stellt. Die Google-Zahlen sehe als Indiz, weil ich keine anderen, besseren Statistiken kenne.

Comment: Moment mal... auch wenn ich in vielen Punkten mit dir d'accord gehe... kann man wirklich von einem Wandel der allgemeinen Formulierung sprechen, wenn es dich nur ein Beispiel gibt, wo's wirklich gemacht wird? "Jedes noch so größte" zum Beispiel hat ein Verhältnis von 1:200.000 zu "jedes noch so große" und meine Beispiele brauche ich garnicht erst nachgucken. Sollte man nicht sinnvollerweise sagen, dass "Jedes noch so kleinste" eine Ausnahme zu einer Regel, die im großen und ganzen intakt ist, zu werden scheint?

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... so wenig es dir auch gefällt, du kannst solche Suchen nicht einfach abtun. Stellt man die geiche Suche mit "jedes noch so große/größte" an, dann kommt man zu ganz anderen Ergebnissen, was definitiv einen Rückschluss darüber erlaubt, wie die Formulierungen verwendet werden ("noch so größte" nämlich garnicht). Klar ist das nicht wissenschaftlich, aber man sieht zumindest Tendenzen. Und da ich nicht glaube, dass Google ein besonderes Interesse daran hat "jede noch so kleinste" zu promoten, gehe ich davon aus, dass beide Ergeibnisse gleich amorph sind.

Comment: @Emanuel Ich leugne nicht, dass sich im Internet Sprache und Sprachgebrauch auf eine bestimmte Weise abbilden. Ich behaupte nur, dass die Art dieser Repräsentation in keiner Weise definiert und dass die Methode im höchsten Maß fragwürdig ist, einfach zwei sprachliche Varianten einzugeben und diejenige, die mehr Treffer hat, als die zu bezeichnen, der im Sinn eines allgemeinen “Sprachwandels” die Zukunft gehört. Ich kenne keine Untersuchung, die den Sprachgebrauch im Internet zum Gegenstand hat, vermutlich gibt es welche, aber sie sind definitiv nicht Grundlage der Argumentation, wie... (->)

Comment: @Emanuel ...sie hier immer wieder betrieben wird. Wie schon weiter oben angedeutet, haben Internetquellen besondere Merkmale, die dabei in keiner Weise berücksichtigt werden, z.B. 1. Internetquellen schreiben hemmungslos voneinander ab (oft wird einfach nur der Wikipedia-Eintrag vervielfältigt), 2. die AutorInnen verwenden oft, weil sie ihrem Internetauftritt ein bestimmtes Sprachniveau geben möchten, ihnen nicht vertraute Wendungen (ein Phänomen, das auch bei Qualifikationsarbeiten auftritt), 3. die Poster schreiben unreflektiert so, wie sie sprechen, was die Kriterien erfolgreicher... (->)

Comment: @Emanuel ...schriftlicher Kommunikation unterläuft, 4. viele Sites “kidnappen” den Sucheintrag, ohne ihn zu enthalten, um Traffic zu generieren. Und das sind nur die Besonderheiten, die mir spontan einfallen und Gründe sind, dieser Form des “Google-Plebiszits” zu misstrauen bzw. eine wesentlich genauere Auseinandersetzung damit zu verlangen.